# Are blob StorageExceptions to be expected when using Azure App Service Logging?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-web-app-service

Every 30 or 40 minutes I see the following exception when streaming application logs from our Azure Website sorry.... Azure Web App :-)

```
Application: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
Application:    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
Application:    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext)
Application:    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
Application:    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext)
Application:    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob.PutBlockList(IEnumerable`1 blockList, AccessCondition accessCondition, BlobRequestOptions options, OperationContext operationContext)
Application:    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.WebSites.Diagnostics.AzureBlobTraceListener.AppendStreamToBlob(Stream stream)
Application:    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.WebSites.Diagnostics.AzureBlobTraceListener.ConsumeBuffer()
Application: Request Information
Application: RequestDate:Thu, 26 Mar 2015 22:58:05 GMT
Application: StatusMessage:The specified block list is invalid.
Application: ErrorCode:InvalidBlockList
```

Is this to be expected when you have diagnostic logging enabled on an Azure App Service? Is it just a First Chance Exception to just ignore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception stack trace does not include your Service Bus Queue call, so it should not be caused by you calling [SendAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queueclient.sendasync.aspx). AzureBlobTraceListener is a [.NET trace listener](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracelistener(v=vs.110).aspx) that uploads all the trace and debug output to Azure Blob service. It looks like it is experiencing an issue while uploading those blobs.

We confirmed that this is a bug in AzureBlobTraceListener and it is now fixed. Thank you for reporting this and we apologize for the inconvenience.

If, however, your App service logging was not supposed to be enabled in the first place, please see [Enable diagnostics logging for web apps in Azure App Service](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log/) for more information.

Comment: Alright not sure where I got so side tracked in thinking the two were correlated :-/  Thank you for the response and the links. I modified the question (hopefully that was alright) to be more accurate.. As  that seemed more useful then the nonsense that the question was.

Comment: The exception itself is certainly not expected. I wanted to make sure logging is intentionally enabled on your service. I already forwarded the question to an internal team, but please also feel free to file a support ticket.

Comment: Logging was intentionally enabled and it was set to information so it was logging a fairly aggressive amount of data. The exception isn't causing any issues (that i know of) but was just curious its origin or if I should be concerned. For now I disabled blob storage for logging and just setup Table Storage set to level "ERROR" and I'm not seeing anymore exceptions. :-) So I'll run with that for now..

Comment: Great! I'm glad the exception is gone. I'm still following up with the team and will update the answer as soon as I have more information.

Comment: We confirmed that this is a bug in AzureBlobTraceListener and will fix it in an upcoming release. Thank you for reporting this and we apologize for the inconvenience. Updated the answer with the same info.

Comment: The fix for this issue has been deployed, so please feel free to enable blob logging if needed for your application.

Comment: @SerdarOzler-Microsoft We're still seeing this issue on our sites. Is the trace listener at least retrying or if we see this, does it mean our log item was totally lost?